# Cannot perform relative import

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

В папке с исполняемым файлом находится еще 1 папка под названием  `casino_data` в ней есть файл под названием `casino_settings.py` и другие json файлы. Требуется импортировать в исполняемый файл, все что находится в `casino_settings.py` моя попытка:

```
from .casino_data.casino_settings import *
```

На что я получаю ошибку:

> Cannot perform relative import

Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте абсолютный импорт.

***Пример:***

```py
from casino_data.casino_settings import *
```

---

Вот, что говорит об этом [документация](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references):

> Note that relative imports are based on the name of the current
> module. Since the name of the main module is always "**main**",
> modules intended for use as the main module of a Python application
> must always use absolute imports.